# Detecting LED state of a device using optocouplers

Tags: led, opto-isolator, switching, low-power

I am trying to convert a dumb ice maker to a smart device with the following control board (5V LED.) My aim is to check the state of these LEDs using an optocoupler isolation board (4-5 channel 3.3V to 5V) without dropping volt/current and send it to an ESP32.

I am not sure if the isolation board would work here as the traces do not seem straight forward.

Control board front/back:

[image: Control Board Front]

[image: Control Board Back Trace]

PC817 based optocoupler board:

[image: 4 Channel Optocoupler Isolation Board]

Comment: How do you know that board isolates anything without a manual or schematics? Unless you find a manual or schematics, nobody can tell you how it works. Where did you buy it?

Comment: It looks like your opto-isolator board has all the grounds connected together, which is the opposite of what you want for this

Comment: @user253751 you're right! I might have cut the ground trace for the inputs and remove the jumpers

Comment: you can deal with the outputs having connected grounds, but the inputs have to be disconnected

Answer (score 1):

The two green LEDs are in reverse-parallel and connected to pins 2 & 5 of CN1. That means that whatever is limiting the current to them is off-board.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqPOqk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Possible driver arrangements.*

If it's an AC drive it will be something like 1a. If it's DC it could be like 1b:

```
BUF1   BUF2   D3   D4
 0      0     Off  Off
 0      1     Off  On
 1      0     On   Off
 1      1     Off  Off
```

Your isolation board isn't going to work for you in this case. Edit your question to show the front panel or type in what exaclty each of the LEDs indicates.

Answer (score 0):

It is not really possible to do directly with optocouplers - not unless there was plenty of excess voltage available driving the LEDs, and the LED series resistors could be changed to a lower value, to compensate for the forward voltage of the optocoupler LED.

Most likely, the LED drive circuit uses 5V or 3.3V, and there won't be enough forward voltage and possibly also current to add an optocoupler junction in series without making the LEDs dim (if 5V) or just plain not turn on at all (if 3.3V).

The circuit you'd use needs to either measure current or voltage across the LED junctions.

If the LED is bypassed by a resistor, the voltage across it - when off - will be close to 0V. On the other hand, when the LED is ON, it'll have >1V across. An "instrumentation comparator" can detect those voltages.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRfCxW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

R1 is installed across the LED on the display board. Two wires then carry the differential voltage down to the comparator.

R8 provides hysteresis to prevent the output from chattering.

All resistors can be 1% tolerance, with exception of R1 and R8, which can be 5%. R2-R5 can come from a resistor array (in a SMD or DIP package), with R4 and R5 being two 470kΩ in parallel each.

There is an "auxiliary" supply (V2) needed for the optocouplers, but that can come from the control board on the fridge, so there's no need to really add an external supply.

The pair of wires from the monitored LED to the "instrumentation comparator" should be ideally twisted pair, but due to C1 that's probably not necessary. The circuit should react in a couple of ms.

The comparators can be jellybean types - LM393, LM2904, LM339, LM2901, for example. More modern rail-to-rail input types will also work.

Since you want five channels, two quad comparators will do the job, say LM393 or LM2901, or three double comparators like LM339 or LM2901.

The 2.5V virtual ground derived by R10 and R11 can be shared for all four channels.

For the two pairs of LEDs that are connected in parallel - LED2,LED3 and LED4,LED5 - only one R1 and C1 is needed. Two channels will monitor those LEDs in parallel.

The complete circuit would have, for the 5 channels needed:

- 3 shunt resistors for the monitored LED (R1A..R1D)
- 3 x 100nF filter capacitors (C1A..C1D)
- 5 series resistors for the optocouplers (R9A..R9D)
- 10 x 2M2 resistors (R6A..D, R7A..D).
- two resistors for the 2.5V divider (R10, R11)
- two decoupling capacitors (for 5V and 2.5V - C3, C2 respectively)
- 3 x 8-resistor 470k individual resistor arrays (e.g. DIP16)
- 2 x LM339/LM2901 (DIP14)

24 parts total, and a total parts cost <$10. The optocouplers will dominate the BOM probably.

The unused optocoupler should have its inputs connected per the datasheet suggestion. Both inputs can go to ground usually, output left floating.

There are other ways of doing it, but this one is fairly robust I think. It requires minimal modification to the LED circuit.

A 6-wire cable - can be a ribbon cable - is needed to connect the LEDs to the comparator/driver board.

Comment: excellent breakdown! If possible, do you think you'd be able to expand circuit this to 5 channel. I haven't worked with resistor array network

Answer (score 0):

You can often use sensitive opto-isolators to monitor standard LEDs.  But the 4-channel board you show is probably NOT suitable.

Most opto-isolators have a forward voltage of about 1.3 - 1.6 Vdc.  Most visible LEDs have a forward voltage of 1.7 to 3 Vdc.  Older Red LEDs have a forward voltage of about 1.7 Vdc.  Older Green and Yellow LEDs have a forward voltage of about 2.1 Vdc.  Modern Green, Blue, White LEDs have a forward voltage of about 3 Vdc.

So: Identify which LEDs you have.  If you can SAFELY measure the LED voltage while the device is operating, make those measurements.

Now choose the appropriate series resistors for the inputs of the opto-isolators.  The resistor value depends on how sensitive the opto-isolator is.  But let's assume that 1mA is lots of current.

Now it's up to you.  Go to Digikey and search for suitable opto-isolators.  Check the datasheets for the LED forward voltage.  As I mentioned earlier, this will be somewhere between 1.3 - 1.6 Vdc.

Calculate the series resistors.  (Visible LED voltage) minus (opto LED voltage) divided by 1mA

Use two wires from each LED on the board to the board containing the opto-isolators.  Be certain to get the polarity correct.

Holler back to us if this doesn't make complete sense to you.  We will help you figure it out.